# Declare global which adds properties to functions

Tags: typescript

I want to declare that all functions can have `disconnectedCallback` as property. How would I do that? (All functions in that file do have this property and I do not want to create a type/interface)

```
function Clock() {
  ...
  Clock.disconnectedCallback = () => { ... }; // Property 'disconnectedCallback' does not exist on type 'typeof Clock'.ts(2339)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Found it.

```
declare global {
  interface Function {
    disconnectedCallback(): void
  }
}
```